# SQL Command to zero pad a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database column that is a text string. Some of the values are like

```
"12345"
```

and some are as year + sequential number like:

```
 "2016-1, 2016-2, 2016-3, 2017-1, 2017-2, 2017-3" etc.
```

I want to update the column values to

```
"2016-001, 2016-002, 2016-003, 2017-001, 2017-002, 2017-003"
```

for the entire table.
I'm not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated. I already updated my stored procedure as such to generate new numbers with zero padding like:

```
rptnum = cast(year(getdate()) as varchar)
 + '-' + RIGHT('000'+ISNULL(Cast((select count(*) 
from dbo.tablename where rptyr = (year(getdate()))) + 1 as varchar),''),3),
```

Comment: Is it always `yyyy-n`, with only 1 digit after the dash? Or can it be several digits after the dash?

Comment: Well it can be several after it gets to higher numbers. 2016-10, 2016-100. It never exceeds 3 for each year.

Comment: getdate() takes current year, so you would have 2017 everywhere

Comment: That function is on an approval. So it basically assigns the next number in sequence with other numbers assigned for the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
select left(rptnum, charindex('-', rptnum))+right('000'+substring(rptnum, charindex('-', rptnum)+1, 10), 3)
```